# textblock run wants to wrap

Tags: c#, wpf

```
 <TextBlock Name="PreviewTextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontFamily="Arial">
            <Run x:Name="PreTextRun" ></Run>
            <Run x:Name="FieldTextRun"></Run>
            <Run x:Name="PostTextRun"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
```

this my WPF code. I load this text block into one stack panel. when text exceeds that stack panel width text wrap wants to perform how?

Comment: could you please include the code for the container(stack panel)

Comment: If you paste your code into a **clean** `StackPanel`, the wrapping is working, so you need to post the code for the `StackPanel`.